# Django timezone: feeling a bit confused

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone, utc

So, we have 'Europe/Moscow' TZ in our settings.
Currently this means daylight saving (this is going to change in the future, but at the moment it's UTC+03/04).

I understand that this TZ is used when saving dates to the DB, and when extracting them.

Now, I have to serialize the datetime object to ISO string, including the UTC offset. What is the correct way of doing this?

The dates don't contain the TZ info (i.e. d.strftime('%z') is empty)

I think I could convert them to UTC and serialize with +00:00, but how do I convert them to UTC if I don't know if the specific date is +03 (Moscow winter) or +04 (Moscow summer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how do I convert them to UTC if I don't know if the specific date is +03 (Moscow winter) or +04 (Moscow summer)

There is no need for UTC conversion, pytz handles such thing for you.

Here's the code to convert from timezone-naive datetime to ISO with timezone offset:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

server_timezone = timezone('Europe/Moscow')

server_timezone.localize(datetime(2011, 1, 1)).isoformat()
>>> '2011-01-01T00:00:00+03:00'

server_timezone.localize(datetime(2011, 7, 1)).isoformat()
>>> '2011-07-01T00:00:00+04:00'
```

Answer (score 3):

First run `new_dt = datetime.replace(tzinfo=tz)` to create a new timezone-aware `datetime`. Then run your `datetime.strftime()` with `%z`.

Note that you can't then convert the date string back to a timezone-aware datetime directly -- `datetime.strptime()` doesn't support `%z`. So you need to instead create a naive `datetime` and a `tzinfo` then do `datetime.replace(tzinfo=tz)` as before.

Some useful external libraries:

http://pytz.sourceforge.net/

http://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/

http://labix.org/python-dateutil

Also try searching right here on Stack Overflow for more questions on (Python OR django OR appengine) AND (datetime OR timezone OR date OR time OR tzinfo).

Comment: By saying `new_dt = datetime.replace(tzinfo=tz)` what do you mean by `tz`? I know the date was saved by Django with 'Europe/Moscow' in mind. How could I convert it to UTC / whatever? What should be passed as `tz`?

Comment: Take a look at the `pytz` link it posted it has a bunch of `tzinfo` items for real timezones you can pass to that function as the `tzinfo` part.

Comment: I accepted an answer from @sayap as more specific, but I thank you for your early hint, and put an upvote here.

Answer (score 1):

ISO-8601 has no notion of "Timezones", only dates and times, and as a convenience, times may be presented with an "offset".

To make matters even more annoying, `datetime` has only a half-hearted nod in acknowledgement of timezones; the tzinfo attribute on datetime objects is optional, and no implementation of that interface is provided by the main-line python.

The standard answer to this is to just always do everything in UTC; including having the server in UTC, not in local time.  This is actually a pretty good idea;  it's not the times that are different, only the way individual users prefer to read those times (which is similar to preferring '42' over '0b101010').

You can satisfy your users' (reasonable!) desire to view times in their local timezone by storing the preferred timezone (perhaps just a sitewide preference if everyone is in Moscow) separately from the actual times, and then you can use a robust timezone library (like [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/)) to do the formatting to and from local time.

Comment: this is all correct and understandable. unfortunately, the site is already working for some time (I've just joined the team), and the dates are already in the DB stored by Django having Europe/Moscow in settings. so, any chance I could recover UTC time from these data?

Comment: Is that your question? it's not clear from your original question that you are trying to migrate a database from localtime to UTC.  If that's so, you should update your question.

Comment: I'm not migrating the DB. I have to output the datetime from the DB in ISO format with the correct offset. I think, the last sentence of the question clearly states that: "how do I convert them to UTC if I don't know if the specific date is +03 (Moscow winter) or +04 (Moscow summer)"